# Unvote a producer

Tags: eosio-code, block-producer, voting, eosio.system

I am working on eosio.system contract, I run my own local chain, in which I elect 5 block-producers and they start to produce block. Now let suppose I want to kick-out any block-producer from my network then how can I do it ?

1. Is there any unvote action in eosio to unvote block-producer ?
2. Do I have to re-call voting process again and vote all bp producers except this ? (I tried it, but it is not working on less than 21 block-producers)

Comment: the one who get max votes will be the producer, so register new producer and vote it

Comment: I don't want to vote any other producer but want to unvote specific bp-producer.